# Why am I receiving an ArrayTypeMismatchException error despite the providing the current return type?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add an item to a List. However everytime I try to add something to that list I face an **ArrayTypeMismatchException** error with the error message being "Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array".

```
Dim params as New List(of OracleParameter)
params.Add(OracleParameterFactory.CreateIn(usedId, OracleDbType.Varchar2))
```

The method "CreateIn" has a return type of OracleParameter. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error at all. Any help will be much appreciated.

Here's the definition for CreateIn

```
Public Shared Function CreateIn(ByVal name as String, ByVal type as OracleDbType) As OracleParameter

Dim p as New OracleParameter()

p.ParameterName = name
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
p.OracleDbType = type
If type = OracleDbType.Varchar2 Then
     p.Size = 4000
End If
p.Value = DBNull.Value

Return p

End Function
```

The same definition and implementation is working in another application without issue if that's any help.

Till now I have cleaned and rebuilt the solution, removed the System library from the project, manually deleted the **bin** and **obj** folders but nothing has yet fixed the problem.

Comment: It should be `Dim params as New List(of OracleParameters)`, but you ought to get a `NullRefrenceException` -- `params` is bad name. -- Can you post `Method1()`?

Comment: Copy paste the exact code. Capitalization and pluralization are wrong and a dead giveaway we may not have all the information. `Dim params as List(of OracleParameters)` should be `Dim params As New List(Of OracleParameter)`. Because `OracleParameters` is not a class, it is `OracleParameter`, and if you don't have the `New` keyword then you will have a `NullReferenceException` (as @Jimi said)

Comment: I made a typo. The New keyword was indeed there. I have also included the definition for Method1

Comment: The `Add()` method adds something returned by `OracleParameterFactory.CreateIn()`, but you posted the `CreateOut()` method, which doesn't seem to return anything. Try to post correct code and enough context to understand what's happening there.

Comment: My apologies again. It will be CreateIn(). The code is identical in both methods except that the Direction property is toggled based on the name.

Comment: The Function is still incomplete (the returned object is nowhere to be seen). Also, the context of these operations is missing, too. -- Note that should the Function return an incorrect Type, you'd have a compilation error, not an `ArrayTypeMismatchException`, which is related to arrays. -- Change the name of that List.

Comment: Fixed what you pointed out. I thought that a type mismatch would generate an issue during compilation but that didn't happen. But I have no idea why I am getting this error during runtime. I'll try changing the name of the List to see if it fixes anything. Please let me know what further context are you looking for? I'm trying to execute a stored procedure and this is how I'm passing the parameters to it.

Comment: If you have any form of threading there, add this information. A List is not thread-safe, if it goes out of sync the internal methods (that handle arrays), may cause that exception. -- Double check whether the exception is thrown by that piece of code and not something else that makes the code execution *jump*. Get the call stack and see if you can determine the line of code that throws it.